# How long can I safely leave my Macbook Pro running?

Tags: macbook-pro

I've set up my Macbook Pro 2011 to run a linux home server through virtualbox. I noticed that this laptop seems to get hot after a few hours compared to my previous laptop (toshiba, windows 8) which I could leave running for days and it never heated up. I am curious though how long I can safely run my Macbook without putting it to sleep? (I have NoSleep installed) I have no problems rebooting once a week or so, just want to know for certain if this actually necessary, cause otherwise I'd put a fan on it and stick it in a corner and forget about it. CPU usage seems to be around 10% when running the server from what Activity Monitor is telling me.

Answer (score 4):

Laptops weren't developed with acting as servers in mind.

The overall-quality of the integrated components is lower than those of common servers. Additionally redundancy for important parts (like the cooling system etc.) is not given.

Especially consumer hard disks and the whole cooling system aren't designed to be run 24/7 a week and guarantee a long lifespan.

The in-case temperature will be generally higher than in a normal server.

This will effect particularly low-cost hard disks. The durability of hard disks may decrease with [higher](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/5730/en/) temperatures. (Opposite standpoint: [Google](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/disk_failures.pdf))

Namely the Macbook Pro 2011 (i own one myself) heats up fast.

I always would advise to get a (cheap) MacMini, set it up headless and store in  a vibration-free place.

If you insist on using your MBP as server, use something like SMC Fan Control (as mentioned/advised by yourself and [dwightk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/70930/dwightk) , choose a vibration-free place and [don't close the lid](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-Questions/How-to-prevent-and-deal-with-overheating/td-p/295146). Most laptops rely on losing some of their heat through the keyboard. Try to disable the discrete graphics card by turning off 2D/3D acceleration in your VirtualBox VM (please check this [ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11111)).

Comment: Agree. My Mac Pro has been running constantly 24/7, only rebooting for system updates, for over 6 years. I wouldn't do that to a laptop & expect it to last anything like the same length of time. Mini is a good budget alternative.

Comment: So if I use something like SMC Fan Control to keep the temperature low, would I be okay atleast for a few months? I don't plan on running the server permanently, and like I said I can reboot at times if needed.

Comment: @macbookowner that's the only thing you can do if you have no other choice. A vibration-free place for your MBP has the same importance. What's the purpose of the Linux-server? Development? A reboot doesn't help much to cool it down, since the temperature will be lowered only for a few minutes...

Comment: Okay, I will also ensure the environment is vibration free. If needed, I can shut the laptop off for several hours, maybe a full day once a week if this would help.

Comment: Couldn't it be better to have the lid closed, since you're then not using the graphics card & monitor anymore, hence resulting in a lower overall temperature?

Comment: @Asmus Just enable "Computer sleep never" and "Monitor sleep 1 min" in the energy saver prefs.

Comment: Are Minis actually that different from MacBook Pros? They always seemed to be using more or less the same components, but in a smaller package without the keyboard and display.

Comment: Since the hard drive is the component that's most likely to be affected by heat, I'd get a firewire or USB hard drive and run from that. the 2011 MBP has USB 2.0, so it might be a little slow for your main hard drive, Firewire is about twice as fast. A Thunderbolt drive would be even better, but they tend to be expensive and you start to get to the point where you'd be better off just buying a Mac Mini.

Answer (score 2):

It should be fine setting it and forgetting it. You might want to manually raise the minimum fan speed just a bit. It is usually running at about 2000rpm for noise reasons, but if you bump the minimum to 3000 it will keep the computer cooler. You can use [SMC Fan Control](http://www.eidac.de) or (I use) [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) to adjust the minimum fan speed.

Comment: I will definitely be looking into this later. Heat is the main thing I'm concerned about, I had no idea I could alter the fan speeds, thank you.

Comment: I would also suggest a cooling pad. I use an old laptop from 2007 as a server (MICROSOFT SERVER 2008) and use a cooling pad to keep the temps down. http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834992853